Why does not work my spring cloud project on docker
I have a problem with docker.
There are 2 service in my project.
1-accounts
2-configserver
https://github.com/trkhmrt/spring_cloud.git
When I start project on local there is no problem but run it on docker I can't get my profile info class prop return null to me.
can u help me ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
